# Access DBFS root with Shared Cluster

Tags: databricks

I have a Unity-Catalog enabled Databricks Workspace with a `shard` cluster. Before teams were working with an `No Isolated Shared Cluster` and were writing/reading files to/from `DBFS`. I know that using `DBFS` in combination with `unity catalog` is not recommendet (see [here](https://docs.databricks.com/en/files/index.html)) but we need it during the transition phase.

As described [here](https://docs.databricks.com/en/data-governance/table-acls/any-file.html) I granted selected users the `ANY FILE` privilige.

```
%sql
GRANT SELECT ON ANY FILE TO `XXX`
```

However, when running the legacy code such as the following

```
with open("/dbfs/FileStore/test.txt", "r") as outfile:
    print(outfile)
```

I get the following error:

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
> '/dbfs/FileStore/test.txt'

How can I mount the `DBFS root` without making (significant) code changes.